Software for warehouse management
I'm looking for warehouse management software with the basic features of asset warehouse software. It should specifically be able to track the assets so that the asset location is clear at any moment in time.
For now, it doesn't matter if it's opensource or proprietary. Also, at this point, any platform i.e. Windows, Linux, macOS is fine.

I suggest looking at ERPNext

It is opensource.
It is based on Frappe framework, hence extensible.
It is currently one of the popular opensource implementations.
Read more about its warehouse management here.


Thanks. I'm going to take a look :)

I may say that a competent rival might be: https://github.com/odoo/odoo

Other options are: https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it and https://foss.heptapod.net/tryton/ and https://github.com/openwms/org.openwms
